# How to use jenkins to build client-server projects

Tags: jenkins

The application I am looking to build is a distributed system with a server (and several other components) running on a linux machine and a client on the windows machine. At every commit I need to build both the components (linux first and windows next) and run some sanity tests

I installed Jenkins slave on the windows machine, but can't find a plugin which will let me link each build-step in a project to a different machine. 
i.e I need to say

- Run build-step A on machine M1
- Run build-step B on machine M2
- Run build-step C on machine M1

Think I can create three different projects for each of these jobs and create a fourth project and have 3 jobs triggering the 3 projects in the required order ("Trigger/call builds on other projects). Is this the only way to do it or is there a plug-in I can use to choose a different machine for each build-step in a project.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your slaves set up, you can tag them with labels like "windows", "linux", etc.  Then you can restrict your jobs to only run on nodes with certain labels.

See [Jenkins: The Definitive Guide](http://books.google.com/books?id=m0n_yhblGysC&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=jenkins%20slave%20label&source=bl&ots=F4OFGqMrT7&sig=iSM8HNfU1AjJI-XNFJdFXEakLcY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C32VUY-WDou1rgGMkIGYAw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=jenkins%20slave%20label&f=false) for more details.

Comment: This will restrict the entire project to run on the label right? What I want is to have the individual build steps in the same build to run on different machines..i.e like the option "Restrict where this project can be run", is there a "Restrict where this build-step can be run".

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that.  But I think your terminology is confusing.  You are using "project" when you really mean "job", and you were using "job" instead of "build step".  Or maybe that's not what you mean...it's hard to tell.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I have not paid enough attention to the terminology.  This is my first time with jenkins and so I have not internalized the terms here. I will edit my original post to clarify